# Atomic operations on superscalar processor

Tags: performance, linux-kernel, atomic, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

Atomic functions execute in one simple instruction. They can not be interrupted in mid-stream. If two operations are requested in the same time one must complete before the second proceed. It never sleep. 
On fifteen stage pipe processor how can I be sure in atomic execution of my atomic function? Is atomic operations have bad affect to performance?

Linux have many atomic function completed as one single instruction have type:

```
typedef struct {
    volatile int counter;
} atomic_t;
```

It define like SMP-safe. Hove is it possible to have SMP-safe atomic on superscalar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with what *atomic* means in computer science.  An operation is atomic if it is *indivisible*.  That means it either completely happens or does not happen at all.  Also, the operation is never visible in a partially completed state.

One way to implement atomic operations on an superscaler processor is to treat atomic instructions as a *barrier*.  Before an atomic instruction can execute, all previous instructions must finish executing.  In addition, no instructions after the atomic instruction may start executing until the atomic instruction finishes.  The superscaler processor is effectively turned into a non-superscaler processor for atomic instructions.

This was how atomic instructions were implemented on SPARC processors in the early 2000's.  It worked, but the performance impact was measurable.

Atomic instructions typically lock the bus while accessing memory.  This keeps other cores from reading or writing memory while the atomic instruction is being done.  Thus other cores don't observe the instruction in a partially completed state.

Comment: On modern CPUs you very rarely resort to a full bus lock, the impact is simply too big. Instead, you can rely on cache coherence and apply most locks locally inside the cores.